# How to let Hibernate 3 to retrieve a value only when its getter is called

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a Hibernate 3 mapping of a table with a medium text field. The table has a few thousands records, other than the medium text field, other fields do not hold much data at all.

The whole table needs to be loaded into memory Except the medium text field, which is very rarely used.

Although I have heard of lazy fetching annotation, however this legacy piece of code is using Hibernate XDoclet, which does not mention lazy fetching in its hibernate property definition:

[http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/tags/hibernate-tags.html#@hibernate_property_*0*_1_](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/tags/hibernate-tags.html#@hibernate_property__0__1_)

So is there any way to tell Hibernate only to retrieve the value when its getter is called?

Comment: check this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using `lazy=true` on the Hibernate property and it does not work, Hibernate still fetches the entire table even when the property is not `get`ed.

As a workaround, I removed the Hibernate property and replaced it by JDBC query in getter, and JDBC statement in setter.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate default supportd lazy fetching unless exlplicity set it to Eager fetching.
If you want to get some idea on lazy fetching refer [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)

If it is property laza loading try something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping 
> 
<class 
name="db.hibernateSimple.Copay" 
table="EHR_COPAY" 
polymorphism="explicit" 
> 

<id 
name="id" 
column="COPAY_ID" 
type="long" 
unsaved-value="null" 
> 
<generator class="sequence"> 
<param name="table">HIVAL</param> 
<param name="column">NEXT</param> 
<!-- 
To add non XDoclet generator parameters, create a file named 
hibernate-generator-params-Copay.xml 
containing the additional parameters and place it in your merge dir. 
--> 
</generator> 
</id> 

<property 
name="balance" 
type="int" 
column="balance" 
length="10" 
/> 

<property 
name="date" 
type="java.lang.String" 
column="OWNERSHIP_DATE" 
/> 

<property 
name="comments" 
type="java.lang.String" 
column="comments" 
lazy="true" 
/> 

<many-to-one 
name="user" 
class="db.hibernateSimple.User" 
cascade="none" 
outer-join="auto" 
column="USER_ID_SEQ" 
/>
```

I extracted the above from [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=938730) you can get some idea I guess